# Dagger classes not being generated

Tags: android, dagger-2, annotation-processor

I have been trying to include Dagger latest version dagger-android:2.11 in my app. But, Daggerclaases like DaggerAppComponent is not being generated.

following is my app level gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.maskery.android.lab.lawyerapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
}
```

my component interface

```
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

my module class

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private LawyerApp app;

    public AppModule(LawyerApp app) {
        this.app = app;
    }


    @Provides public Context providesContext(){
        return app;
    }

    @Provides public Resources providesResources(){
        return app.getResources();
    }

}
```

the app is properly building but when am trying to create AppComponent object, DaggerAppComponent is just not availbale.

I have enabled annotation processing in the settings and created this app only after that.

I tried 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' plugin too,. This also didnt work for me.

This is like hit-end for me over any options to try here. Please help.

Comment: add  `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11` to your build.gradle file

Comment: The dagger 2 for the Android document in the official site doesn't mention it.

Comment: Added the suggested line, didn't help. Then I removed >>annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'<<, keeping the suggested line, didn't work. Please help.

Comment: have you checked the docs?  `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11' 
 and  `annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11`

Comment: Generally, if Dagger isn't generating classes, it's because either you haven't added the right annotation processor _or_ Dagger or Java encounters an error and halts compilation. Can you please check your error logs for the latter?

Comment: Did you include Dagger dependencies in the same module as the one you require it in?

I just verified that dagger dependencies can't be exposed as an api using gradle. You need to import dagger dependencies in all the modules you are using them.

So let's say your Android module1 depends on Android module2, and you include dagger with äpi" keyword in gradle, using Dagger annotations in module1 will pass. However, any components or modules you write in module1 will not have any generated implementers. Only the components, modules etc in module2 will have generated implementers.